# Can I apply D-noise to a folder of rendered stills of an animation?

Tags: rendering, animation

I wanted to apply the D-Noise filter to an animation and I suppose there must be a way to apply it as each still is rendered but I couldn't find it and had to start my render to meet a deadline. My stills are pretty noisy as I am using emission so would be great if there is some way to apply it to a folder.

I'm sure there is a way in Python but I cannot really do anything at all in Python so please any other way.

Comment: Do you mean *denoise*?

Comment: @RayMairlot They likely mean Grant Wilk's add-on (https://remingtongraphics.net/tools/d-noise/) to use Nvidia's OptiX denoiser.

Comment: Did you have a **scene** for that animation? If you don't provide extra information to OptiX, then it won't work: [D-NOISE for plane](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149508/using-d-noise-for-denoising-photos/149509#149509)

Answer (score 0):

So it just turns out that if you render to stills and then use the Blender video sequencer to run those stills together into a video file you can just enable D-Noise at the bottom of the view 'Layer tab' - it slows things down a fair bit but it works a treat.

Comment: **But...** *Optix* is designed for stills. The output is different from frame to frame and can lead into glitches so I'd say unusable for hq animations.

Comment: Video denoisers seem to be pretty good at removing the remaining low frequency noise but can leave slight trailing artifacts depending on the settings and algorithm used.